# Regex code for validating credit card in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for regex code for validate credit card in JavaScript. For example if i type first number 4 then its innerhtml print VISA

```
"use strict"
function $(x) { return document.querySelector(x) };

$("input").addEventListener("input", function () {

    var x = this.value;
    var patt=/\s*(\d(?:\s*)){16}\s*/

    if( patt.test(x)){
        
        this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML="Match"
    }
    else{
        this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML="no Match"
    }

});
```

Comment: Please refer to references [such as this one](https://regular-expressions.mobi/creditcard.html?wlr=1) which provide patterns and rules for the major CC providers.

Comment: much helpful website link thank you so much TJ